# Connecting to an ipv6 website using OpenSSL

Tags: python, ssl, ssl-certificate, ipv6

I tried this code which I got from a reference to connect to ipv6 server using OpenSSL inorder to take the SSL certificate documentation of an ipv6 website.

```
ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.TLS_method) #SSLv23_METHOD
ctx.set_verify(ssl.VERIFY_NONE, verify_cb)
ctx.use_privatekey_file (os.path.join(dir, 'client.pkey'))
ctx.use_certificate_file(os.path.join(dir, 'client.cert'))
ctx.load_verify_locations(os.path.join(dir, 'CA.cert'))
#Set up client
sock = ssl.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
sock.connect(('2406:da18:9be:7600::/64',443,0,2))
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
<ipython-input-1-073384200f70> in <module>
  5 import certifi
  6 
----> 7 ctx = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.TLS_method) #SSLv23_METHOD
  8 ctx.set_verify(ssl.VERIFY_NONE, verify_cb)
  9 ctx.use_privatekey_file (os.path.join(dir, 'client.pkey'))

AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'TLS_method'
```

it was so hard to find a method to get the SSL certification for the ipv6 website although there is a method for ipv4. Can you help me to find the issue in here and are there any other ways to get the ipv6 SSL certification?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IPv6 vs. IPv4 and nothing to do with certificates. This is a compile time error in your code, complaining about an undeclared attribute you are using. I have the feeling that you try to apply the syntax from pyopenssl to pythons native ssl library. But the code is not complete enough to be sure.